# Select file or directory in SwiftUI in an AppKit App

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

How can I display a file dialogue in SwiftUI to choose a directory or file.

I think using a NSViewRepresentable to wrap a NSOpenPanel will not work, as it expects a NSView not a NSPanel.

Any alternative ideas, tips or links?
Everything I found was about UIKit.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63764764/12299030?

Comment: Thanks, didn't remember

Answer (score 8):

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FolderSelector: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Choose Folder") {
            self.selectFolder()
        }
    }
    
    func selectFolder() {
        
        let folderChooserPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let folderChooserSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 600)
        let folderChooserRectangle = CGRect(origin: folderChooserPoint, size: folderChooserSize)
        let folderPicker = NSOpenPanel(contentRect: folderChooserRectangle, styleMask: .utilityWindow, backing: .buffered, defer: true)
        
        folderPicker.canChooseDirectories = true
        folderPicker.canChooseFiles = true
        folderPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        folderPicker.canDownloadUbiquitousContents = true
        folderPicker.canResolveUbiquitousConflicts = true
        
        folderPicker.begin { response in
            
            if response == .OK {
                let pickedFolders = folderPicker.urls
                
                self.selectedFolder.getFileList(at: pickedFolders)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like how this answer uses *begin* instead of RunModal as seen in other responses