# NSOpenPanel Method on ViewModel don't display the return value on the View

Tags: swift, swiftui, properties, wrapper

I am quite new in development but I am progressing! My idea is to open a database (via NSOpenPanel) and then access the data using different methods.

Below is the model (Model), the ViewModel (and the NSOpenPanel method) as well as the View.

```
import Foundation

// DataBase Model
struct Database {
    var path: [URL?]
    var firstRecord: Date
    var lastRecord: Date
    
}

import AppKit
import SwiftUI

// ViewModel
class DatabaseFileSelectedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published public var path: [Database] = []
    init() {
        self.path = path
    }
    
    // select the file and open the database, sort it by localTime...
    func fileSelected() -> [URL?] {
        var path: [URL?] = [URL?]()
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        
        let response = openPanel.runModal()
        if response == .OK { path = openPanel.urls }
        return path
    }
}

import SwiftUI

// VIEW
struct FileSelectedView: View {
    
    @StateObject var DatabaseFileSelectedVM = DatabaseFileSelectedViewModel()
    
    // Body
    var body: some View {
        HStack (content: {
            VStack (alignment: .leading, content: {
                Button(action: {
                    let pathSelected = DatabaseFileSelectedVM.fileSelected()
                }, label: { Label("Select File…", systemImage: "doc")})
                Divider()
                Text("The File selected is: ")
                Text(pathSelected) // ERROR!
            })
                .font(.headline)
                .padding([.top, .leading], 10)
            Spacer()
        })
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

My question:
The fileSelected() method does return an array of type [URL?], however I don't know how to structure my View so that it incorporates the selected path when validating the file selection window. Also, the compiler tells me Cannot find 'pathSelected' in scope. How to structure my View?

Thank you very much for any thoughts you can give me.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63764764/12299030?

Comment: Unrelated but if you specify `allowsMultipleSelection = false` why do you call the `urls` (plural) API?

Comment: @vadian I don’t think he has a choice. But of course he should return a single url using the first property of the collection and return an optional url.

Comment: @LeoDabus In single selection mode [url](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel/1534384-url) contains always a value if OK is pressed.

Comment: Funny I thought it was deprecated. It doesn’t even show anymore at [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel)

Comment: @LeoDabus Many of the ObjC based APIs don't show the inherited properties and methods in the subclasses.